# PySide6: error while loading shared libraries: libQt6DesignerComponents.so.6: cannot open shared object file

Tags: python, qt-designer, pyside6

I'm trying to run QT Designer from the terminal

```
pyside6-designer
```

but get the error message:

```
venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/designer: error while loading shared libraries: libQt6DesignerComponents.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Inspecting the folder, I can confirm `libQt6DesignerComponents.so.6` exist in the folder:

```
/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/lib
```

I have re-installed and also tried the alternative `PIPENV`, but same result. Trying to execute in the same folder it ask me to install `qtchooser`. But didn't work after installing this.

I am on Ubuntu 20.04. I can find a ticket saying it should be solved. [link to solution](https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/pyside/pyside-setup/+/327680/1/build_scripts/platforms/unix.py#154)

I have also tried some random stuff, such as

```
sudo /sbin/ldconfig -v
```

which is described here [its foss](https://itsfoss.com/solve-open-shared-object-file-quick-tip/). It didn't work.

Anyone got experience of the same problem and have a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your LD_LIBRARY path in shell (bash) after activating a venv:

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/***FILL_IN_USERNAME***/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/lib/

I'm running Kubuntu Groovy Gorilla.

I'm quite excited about trying this out.